# Removing "" marks from saved txt

Tags: r

I am trying to save a dataframe of characters.

I tried:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c1= "abc",c2="def",c3="ghi")
df1

write.table(df1, "df1.txt")
```

But the file contains everything with "" marks:

```
"c1" "c2" "c3"
"1" "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

How can I save the file with no `""` marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `quote=FALSE`

From the documentation of write.table:

```
write.table(x, file = "", append = FALSE, quote = TRUE, sep = " ",
            eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = TRUE,
            col.names = TRUE, qmethod = c("escape", "double"),
            fileEncoding = "")
```

"quote
a logical value (TRUE or FALSE) or a numeric vector. If TRUE, any character or factor columns will be surrounded by double quotes. If a numeric vector, its elements are taken as the indices of columns to quote. In both cases, row and column names are quoted if they are written. If FALSE, nothing is quoted."

Answer (score 1):

You could use the option `quote = FALSE`

```
df1 <- data.frame(c1= "abc",c2="def",c3="ghi")
df1

write.table(df1, "df1.txt", quote = FALSE)
```